# Расчёт времени

Tags: php, javascript

Система расчёта времени выполнения задачи , если человек нажимает старт  то время пошло ,
если нажимает стоп то время останавливается и потом результат записывается в базу ,
независимо закрыл браузер пользователь не закрыл ,время должно идти ,и после того как пользователь снова зашел на страницу и нажал стоп ,останавливаться. 
Подскажите пжл как реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если максимально просто - по нажатию кнопки старт ложите в БД значение текущего времени, по нажатию кнопки стоп - считаете время по формуле - текущее-стартовоею Вот собственном все.

Если будет необходимость как-то выводить в браузер что-то типа прошло столько-то столько то  времени таймером то тут уже пример на javascript'e, код писать лениво но идею напишу - делаем ajax запрос на сервер, на сервере считаем разницу текущего времени и времени старта, возвращаем все это дело в виде timestamp, ну а дальше уже выводим, обьект Date в помощь...

Comment: Спасибо за идею ,возник ещё вопрос по поводу того как остановить счётчик по истечению рабочего дня , если человек забыл нажать стоп,вспомнил про cron ,по окончанию рабочего дня cron запустит скрипт который остановит все счётчики .Точнее запишет новое время в таблицу

Comment: да, для этой задачи действительно лучше всего подойдет cron

Answer (score 1):

Если все "по-честному", то алгоритм простой, на сервере SQL таблица:

```
timer_id => status (start/stop), timer (in sec)
```

Ну а на странице ежесекундное обращение к серверу, который по `timer_id` вытаскивает `timer`, и на сервере ежесекундный SQL-запрос:

```
update `timers` set `timer` = `timer` + 1 where `status` = 'start'
```

Плюс скрипты которые по кнопке могут изменить состояние счетчика со `start` на `stop` и наоборот

Если оставить только не совсем "честный" таймер на стороне клиента, то вам понадобится событие `window.onunload` для того что-бы сохранить таймер в базе

Comment: ок, пользователь закрыл браузер, что дальше?:)

Comment: Время на сервере идет

Comment: Ну а на странице ежесекундное обращение к серверу

каким образом?

Comment: AJAX или IFRAME

Comment: Вы не поняли, человек **закрыл браузер**, что дальше, откуда возьмется аякс или ифрейм?:)

Comment: Так таймеры обновляются на сервере:

    #!/bin/bash
    while :
    do
        mysql -e 'update `timers` set `timer` = `timer` + 1 where `status` = "start"'
        sleep 1
    done

Comment: Так а зачем сервер напрягать то, если можно вообще обойтись без этого? О_о

Comment: Можно, просто это была первая пришедшая в голову мысль. две таблицы и пара хранимых процедур (или возможность транзакций) решают задачу